# Delete Line with special character

Tags: c#, file, file-organization

I have a text file like this:

```
hello
this is text file
 * Can you Tell me what is 
 * Dnt Care
 * List item
```

I want to delete all line have asterisk sign (*) so the result in file after deletion is:

```
hello
this is text file
```

Answer (score 5):

LINQ makes this easy:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

...

File.WriteAllLines("output.txt",
                   File.ReadLines("input.txt")
                       .Where(line => !line.Contains("*")));
```

Or as two statements - it's still lazy, only reading a line at a time:

```
var query = File.ReadLines("input.txt").Where(line => !line.Contains("*"));
File.WriteAllLines("output.txt", query);
```

If you definitely need to *replace* the original file, you could *either* use the above and then delete the original file and move the new file into place, *or* (if the file is small enough) read the whole file to start with:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt").Where(line => !line.Contains("*"));
File.WriteAllLines("file.txt", lines);
```

Note that because this uses [`ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx) instead of [`ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx), it will read the *whole* file into memory in one go.

This is assuming you're using .NET 4 or higher. If you're only using .NET 3.5, you can still use the second form, but you need to convert the result into an array before writing it out:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt")
                .Where(line => !line.Contains("*"))
                .ToArray();
File.WriteAllLines("file.txt", lines);
```

Comment: Where do you get Where function to show up for string array?

Comment: @JeremyK: You need a `using` directive for `System.Linq`. Will add that into the answer.

Comment: So glad I decided to browse today, learned something new :) Thank you sir.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you know how to read and write contents from the file, you can use a `Regex` to remove the lines you don't want. This has the advantage that it requires the * to be in the beginning of the line, instead of just present anywhere on it.

```
Regex.Replace(fileContents, "(?m)(^\s*\*.*$)", "");
```

This `Regex` has an optional number of white spaces in front of the *.

Answer (score 1):

Read the lines in the file:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
```

Filter out lines with asterisks:

```
string[] filtered = lines.Where(s => !s.Trim().StartsWith("*")).ToArray();
```

Write the remaining lines to the file:

```
File.WriteAllLines(filename, filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go line by line and see if the string contains a *

```
while(Reader.CanRead())
{
   string currLine = reader.ReadLine();
   if(currLine.Contains("*") == false)
       list.Add(currLine);
}
```

Comment: Clearly the answers above me a far better :)